# Keycode is deprecated what should I replace it with?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently tasked with creating a 2 player html soccer game, I've searched for some codes to understand more and found a code that uses keyCode which is apparently deprecated now. I'm still new here and am currently a college student so I don't know much.

here is the part of the code

```
document.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 87){
        wDown = false;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 65){
        aDown = false;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 68){
        dDown = false;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 83){
        sDown = false;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 38){
        upDown = false;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 37){
        leftDown = false;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 40){
        downDown = false;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 39){
        rightDown = false;
    }
}

document.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 87){
        wDown = true;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 65){
        aDown = true;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 68){
        dDown = true;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 83){
        sDown = true;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 38){
        upDown = true;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 37){
        leftDown = true;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 40){
        downDown = true;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 39){
        rightDown = true;
    }
}
```

I just want help man

Comment: Always refer to MDN in these instances: `You should avoid using keyCode if possible; it's been deprecated for some time. Instead, you should use KeyboardEvent.code` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCodehttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Answer (score 0):

You can also actual characters instead of using the codes. Something like:

```
document.onkeyup = function(event) 
{
    if (event.key === 'w') {
        wDown = false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.key` instead. I have refactored your code to use it as well as changed it to use switch-case instead of if conditions.

```js
let wDown = false,
    aDown = false,
    dDown = false,
    sDown = false,
    upDown = false,
    leftDown = false,
    downDown = false,
    rightDown = false;
document.onkeyup = function(e){
    switch (e.key) {
        case 'w': {
            wDown = false;
        } break;
        case 'a': {
            aDown = false;
        } break;
        case 'd': {
            dDown = false;
        } break;
        case 's': {
            sDown = false;
        } break;
        case 'ArrowUp': {
            upDown = false;
        } break;
        case 'ArrowLeft': {
            leftDown = false;
        } break;
        case 'ArrowDown': {
            downDown = false;
        } break;
        case 'ArrowRight': {
            rightDown = false;
        } break;
    }
    console.log({wDown, aDown, sDown, dDown, upDown, leftDown, downDown, rightDown});
}

document.onkeydown = function(e){
    switch (e.key) {
        case 'w': {
            wDown = true;
        } break;
        case 'a': {
            aDown = true;
        } break;
        case 'd': {
            dDown = true;
        } break;
        case 's': {
            sDown = true;
        } break;
        case 'ArrowUp': {
            upDown = true;
        } break;
        case 'ArrowLeft': {
            leftDown = true;
        } break;
        case 'ArrowDown': {
            downDown = true;
        } break;
        case 'ArrowRight': {
            rightDown = true;
        } break;
    }
    console.log({wDown, aDown, sDown, dDown, upDown, leftDown, downDown, rightDown});
}
```